# How to access a property of Vue object declared on a lower (parent) level?

Tags: javascript, router, vue-router, vue.js, vuex

In my *index.js* I have a Vue object that declares a router and renders the holder for all the pages.

```
const app = new Vue({ 
  ..., 
  render: _ => _(App),
  router, 
  ..., 
  el: "#app-base"});
```

In the page renderer I have components that sequentially have their subcomponents etc. Now I'd like to access the router instance declared on the outmost level and [operate on it in the context of one of the toppy subcomponents](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

How can I achieve that?

It doesn't exist in the context as is. Do I need to pass it up the tree somehow? What would be a good way to do that? Should I avoid the need to access bottomly declared instances in the topply working components?

Comment: In these cases you want to use [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) to manage state between the upper component, and the bottom component.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the store to, well... store the instance of the router? Can do. How about the other consideration? In my mind, **if** there's a need to access the router in the toppy level, one should consider a different approach because that suggest a bad design to begin with. Am I right to be concerned or is it a commonly occurring scenario?

Comment: It's normal to components to intercommunicate. What is avoided is the scope mess that would become handling several components with the same scope... Also, Vuex adds a single point of mutation, which makes it easier to maintain. However it's the first time I see a component communicating with the router. So, there might be another options (;

Comment: @KonradViltersten are you not able to access `this.route` or `this.$route`?

Comment: @saurabh I am able to do that. My question was because of a code review where it was suggested to control the routing from the outermost components. I think highly of competence of the person who suggested it but at the same time I know that he's very bolted down to the pattern of Angular and MVC. Hence me asking here.

Comment: if you want to control the router from the root level you might look into the 'navigation guards' http://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html. they are basically hooks you can define to allow or disallow route transitions

Comment: In that case, you can have a method at root level which takes care of modifying routes, and call it using [Vue events](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) from child components.

Comment: @saurabh I think it's the best for my case. Post it as a reply so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue allows you to access and modify route at vue component level using `this.$route` variable.

However this can be centralised by having generalised methods to modify route at root level component and whenever need to change from child components, call this root level method using [vue-events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on).

---

One can not access data of parent in child directly(there are [ways](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent), but not recommended), but one can call the method of parent using [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c9kpdpx/). In vue it is [props down, event up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) for parent child communication

Comment: It worked out for my current need. Just a quick follow up, though. When you say "*centralize by general methods at root level*" - are you saying that the Vue component would declare a method like *..., methods:{donkey:function(){...}},...*? I'm surprised because I was under the impression that the child components couldn't access the stuff from the parent... When I tried to do that with *data*, I noticed that parent's *data* wasn't available in the child's *data*...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, yes, you will have to define method at root component level. You can not access data of parent in child directly, but you can call the method of parent using [$emit](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c9kpdpx/). In vue it is [props down, event up](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) for parent child communication.